# runApp Shiny Error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, run-app

I am using the runApp() to test a basic web App. I am following the instructions mentioned in this url http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/runApp.html

I am trying to set it up with a host 0.0.0.0 and port 1234 such that users on the same intranet can do some quick testing.

So I added a line right below the `library(shiny)` on my `server.r` file like this below

```
library(shiny)
runApp('.../Shiny Test/Try7',host="0.0.0.0", port = 1234)
```

I am getting an error

```
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:1234
Error in source(file, ..., keep.source = TRUE, encoding =   
checkEncoding(file)) : 
\Shiny Test\Try7/server.R:3:68: unexpected numeric constant
2: library(shiny)
3: runApp('....../Shiny Test/Try7',0.0.0
                                                                  ^
```

Need help learning how to use this function. Thanks folks for helping.

Comment: Not sure this'll entirely solve your problem, but both the `host=` and `port=` arguments expect character strings, which need to be quoted. (So, e.g., do `runApp(..., port="1234", host="0.0.0.0")` .)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I did that and now the app opens in an URL with host 127.0.0.1:1234 and shows an error `R:3:68: unexpected numeric constant Shiny Test/Try7',0.0.0`
                                     `^`

Comment: that shouldnt be in server.R.  Just run the command from your R console

Comment: @bunk, ah, I am getting an error `Error in startPipeServer(port, mask, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) : 
  Failed to create server`...I am assuming this is something with the port not being open or using a bad port ?

Comment: maybe, try without quoting the port though, `runApp(appDir = "app", host='0.0.0.0', port=1234)`

Comment: @bunk, Now i am seeing this error..... `Listening on http://0.0.0.0:1234
Error in startServer(host, port, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) : 
  Failed to create server`

Comment: do you need that port specifically?  if you start it without that you can the see what port it's on.

Comment: @bunk, i dont care I could use any open port. I tried without the port option. I get this error.` Listening on http://0.0.0.0:4472
Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use`

Comment: look through your app.R or server/ui.R and see if you using runApp or something in there

Comment: @bunk, did check for that ...did not see that function used anywhere else. Still the same error :(, I just have ui.r and server.r I dont have app.r...is that necessary for this to work ?

Comment: No, app.R is not necessary if you have a ui.R (or www/index.html) and serve.R. Could you post the code for the app and a explanation of how the files are organized (if your using a www folder or something like this)?

Comment: I don't think 0.0.0.0 is a valid subnet IP, set the app to run on localhost (127.0.0.1) and acces the ap by the computers IP on the subnet (ifconfig to see this on linux)

Comment: @bunk, @Oskar I restarted RStudio and I am now able execute `runApp('....../Shiny Test/Try7',host="0.0.0.0")` it opens up on my browser as `http://127.0.0.1:4472` however when my testers type http://localhost:4472  on their browser it says `connection refused.`

Comment: You can install apps in the /srv/shiny-server if your runing shiny-server on linux

Comment: @OskarForsmo which app Oskar. I have ui.r and server.r files in that folder

Comment: @bunk, thanks bunk your suggestions were very helpful.

Comment: Put the files in a folder (myapp as an example), copy/move the files to /srv/shiny-server,  configure shiny in /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf default port is 3838 then just open a browser and type 192.168.1.256:3838/myapp but change the IP to your IP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92768/discussion-between-oskar-forsmo-and-bridgeport-byron-tucker).

Comment: Okay this worked. What I had to do was type ipconfig and provide my ipaddress to the testers instead of asking them to type localhost:44472 in their browser.